# How to create an event based virtual assistant?

Tags: java, speech-recognition

There are many virtual assistants available in the market, like Siri (Apple), Braina (Windows), various for Android phones. These assistants reply to you based on the questions you ask, or they remind you of a task put in the calendar, or red out an sms, etc.

Is there any API available for Windows/Mac, which I can download and use to create my own virtual assistant? By my own I mean, I will write a program to do some work, and depending on the output the program produces, my virtual assistant will talk to me.

There is AIML, Alicebot, etc. But, I don't want an intelligent assistant to chat with me. I just want a Virtual Assistant UI to read out outputs from a program running in the background.

For example, suppose I am checking how much space is left in my C:/ drive. If space is less that 500MB, my virtual assistant will say, "it is time to clean up your disk". This way, I want to write many such small utility programs to give different kinds of information, and I want my virtual assistant tell me all these.

At present the virtual assistants I found to download in my phone or laptop (as listed above), I cannot feed in my own program.

Any way I can do it? I would like to code this in Java on Windows. If not possible, any other language or OS is fine with me.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure this is the right place to start. SO is more for discussing issues that come while programming. Anyway – I think what you first need is a complete list of things you want to monitor (e.g disk space, up-time, calendar etc...) once you have that list you can check if each specific "problem" can be accessed from a Java-Program or if you need an external tool for that (you can execute windows-terminal commands from java). Once you have all your tools you can start thinking about a Java-program, that runs in the background and executes every now and then some check.

Comment: I have al my Java programs ready. They are monitoring the system in t he background and sending me alerts. But I want a virtual assistant to tell me all these alerts, instead of me printing them in the console, or writing to a file, or flashing a popup.

Comment: My question is regarding programming. I don't know how to program a virtual assistant. I want to know where to start. I searched a lot and found many apps, but no API or code, which I can use to feed in my Java program outputs.

Comment: @kajarigd: What you're actually looking for is a [voice response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_voice_response) application.  A virtual assistant would respond to voice commands as well as reply with a voice response.

Comment: Hi, I don't want voice interactions. I just want the assistant to read out the alert. That's all. There should be lip syncing, and body movement of the assistant to get the feeling that a real human is speaking.

Comment: May be I shouldn't have used the phrase, "virtual assistant"? Should I say, "alert reader bot" or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may want to look into Visemes.  Visemes represent the facial expressions related to the pronunciation of phonemes.  There are several companies that provide this functionality with their TTS products and will even provide the animated avatars that you refer to.  You can find these implementations with a simple search.

If you are looking into creating this yourself, you can start with a pronunciation dictionary such as one provided by CMU Sphinx.

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

Its An Wonderful idea first of all! Where u can actually make ur own Ironman's Jarvis!. Its pretty easy in .Net to work with these kind of application! All you need is
* Visual Studio 2008 or later (I use VB.Net)
* AIMLBot (A chatbot library to make natural conversations) 
* Haptek Character (To display a 3D Virtual Human Character That Can Talk With Animations)

Now you can use this all and can make a talking conversational virtual assistant!! You can make it respond technical details of your computer like Alerting on low disk space, Inform you on new mail and also can open & read mail for you using VB.Net programming to open the mail and pass the content text to your virtual assistant and vice versa!!

Its actually simpler than it sounds!!

Watch this video to build your first Talking 3D avatar using VB.Net

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gh-DPpCqxXY